# bad operand types for binary operator +

Tags: java, operands

I need a large number up to 20 digits and I'm using bigint. It gives me this error(bad operand types for binary operator +) on line below.

```
BigInteger t = new BigInteger(my_number.getText().toString());
                my_number.setText(String.valueOf(t+1));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java does not support operators overloading. Use `add` method: `t.add(BigInteger.ONE)`

Comment: It does not work. I need to sum it. for example 123456 (+1) = 123457

Comment: It does exactly that, adding "1" numerically to the BigInteger. `add` is called on `t` which is a BigInteger, not a string. So it's not string concatenation, but an integer increment.

Comment: Here the full code to make it more clear: `my_number.setText(t.add(BigInteger.ONE).toString());`

Comment: Sorry man, my mistake. It Works. Thank you, I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
 BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("12223");
 BigInteger cvk =  new BigInteger("1");
 System.out.println(String.valueOf(bi.add(cvk)));
```

Hope my help works thanks.